# Magento 2 Use Default Value for Category Image is not working for a specific storeview

Tags: magento2, category, multistore

My Magento website is running in different store views. I have experienced a weired issue, that for just one store view, I can't select **Use Default Value** for the Category Image.

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Magento 2,
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12159

Comment: it's reproduced in Magento 2.2.x and Magento 2.3.x. Have you found any intermediate solution?